# Running a task over time?

Tags: java, time, task, schedule

So I have an NPC and I want it to change its appearance over a period of 5 minutes, or 10 minutes if you are a special player.  The NPC changes twice and then completely removes itself.  Once a player dies this NPC is placed in their current position.  The NPC then starts to degrade over the period of 5 minutes and then eventually removes itself.  This NPC allows the player to grab their lost items before the timer runs out.  While the NPC is there, other players have the option of making the timer reset so they have more time to get there.  I was able to make it degrade and send them a message saying the time they had left to get their items back.  The only problem occurred towards the end, before it destroys itself.  It constantly sends the player a message saying the time they had left rather than just once, and it never gets removed.  Here is the code I have for it:

```
package com.rs.game.npc.others;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import com.rs.game.item.Item;
import com.rs.game.npc.NPC;
import com.rs.game.player.Player;
import com.rs.game.player.Skills;
import com.rs.utils.Logger;

public class Gravestone extends NPC implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3293609625562930841L;
    private transient Player player;
    private long BEGIN_TIME;
    private int currentGrave;
    private final CopyOnWriteArrayList<Item> container;
    private int MAX_TIME = 6*60000;//60000ms = 1 min
    private int INTERFACE = 272;
    private long timeLeft = (long) (System.currentTimeMillis() - BEGIN_TIME);
    private int minutes;

    public Gravestone(Player player, CopyOnWriteArrayList<Item> containedItems) {
        super(6601, player, -1, false, false);
        this.player = player;
        this.BEGIN_TIME = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (player.isDonator())
            this.MAX_TIME *= player.getDonator();

        this.currentGrave = 6601;
        this.container = containedItems;
        setName(player.getDisplayName()+ "'s Gravestone");
        player.sm("A gravestone has been left in the place you died to receive your items click on it.");
    }

    public Gravestone(Player player, CopyOnWriteArrayList<Item> containedItems, long time, int npcId) {
        super(npcId, player, -1, false);
        this.player = player;
        this.container = containedItems;
        setName(player.getDisplayName()+ "'s Gravestone");

    }

    public String getName() {
        return player.getDisplayName()+ "'s Gravestone";
    }
    public void processNPC() {
        if (hasFinished())
            return;
        setName(getName());
        long timeElapsed =  System.currentTimeMillis( ) - BEGIN_TIME;
        int minute = 60000;
        int minutesElapsed = (int) (timeElapsed / minute);
        int maxMinutes = MAX_TIME / minute;
        minutes = maxMinutes - minutesElapsed;
        boolean pause = false;
        if (!pause && (minutes == 5 && getId() == 6601 //first - degrade at 5 minutes stop and wait til unpause
                || minutes == 3 && getId() == 6602 //second - degrade at 3 minutes
                || minutes <= 0 && getId() == 6603)){ //third - degrade at 1 minute
                degradeGraveStone();
                pause = true;
        } else if (pause && (minutes == 4 && getId() == 6602 //second
                    || minutes == 2 && getId() == 6603)) //third
            pause = false;
        Logger.log("GraveStone", "Player "+ player.getDisplayName() +" time elapsed "+ timeElapsed +" minutes left "+ minutes +" Pause? "+pause);
    }

    public void handleOptions(Player p, int id, int npcId) {
        switch (id) {
            case 1:
                sendMemorial(p);
                break;
            case 2:
                if (npcId == 6601)
                    demolishGraveStone(p);
                else 
                    repairGraveStone(p);
                break;
            case 3:
                    blessGraveStone(p);
                break;
            case 4:
                demolishGraveStone(p);
                break;
        }
    }

    private void degradeGraveStone() {
        if (currentGrave < 6603) { 
            graveStoneDegrade(currentGrave + 1);
        } else {
            demolishGraveStone(player);
            return;
        }
        setName(player.getDisplayName()+ "'s Gravestone");
        player.sm("Your gravestone slighlty degrades, you have" + minutes + " minutes to get your items back!");
    }

    private void demolishGraveStone(Player p) {
        if (player != p) {
            p.sm("You cannot destroy a grave that isn't yours!");
            return;
        }
        player.sm("Your gravestone has been destroyed.");
        player.sm("Your items have been added to your bank.");
        for (Item item : container)
            player.getBank().addItem(item.getId(), item.getAmount(), true);

        finish();
    }

    private void blessGraveStone(Player p) {
        if (p.getSkills().getLevel(Skills.PRAYER) < 90){
            p.sm("You need a prayer level of at least 90 to bless this Grave Stone.");
            return;
        }

        p.sm("You bless " + player.getDisplayName() + "'s Grave Stone.");
        player.sm(p.getDisplayName() + " has blessed your GraveStone.");
        graveStoneDegrade(6601);
        setName(player.getDisplayName()+ "'s Gravestone");
        BEGIN_TIME = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    private void repairGraveStone(Player p) {
        if (p.getSkills().getLevel(Skills.CRAFTING) < 75){
            p.sm("You need a crafting level of at least 75 to repair this Grave Stone.");
            return;
        }
        p.sm("You repair " + player.getDisplayName() + "'s Grave Stone.");
        player.sm(p.getDisplayName() + " has repaired your GraveStone.");
        graveStoneDegrade(this.getId() - 1);
        setName(player.getDisplayName()+ "'s Gravestone");
        BEGIN_TIME = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    private void sendMemorial(Player p) {
        p.getInterfaceManager().sendInterface(INTERFACE);
        p.getPackets().sendIComponentText(INTERFACE, 16, getName());
    }

    public Player getPlayer() {
        return player;
    }

}
```

Comment: Perhaps you should add some parenthesis at those conditions inside `processNPC()`. They are unreadable. How many times per second is this method being called?

Comment: Once per second I believe.

Comment: Does this code run by multiple threads? Is it possible to add the log messages you see when the NPC is near to destroy itself? Because if the message you are talking about is the one in `degradeGraveStone() "Your gravestone slighlty degrades, you have x minutes to get your items back!"` I don't know how that's possible. And please add the code for `graveStoneDegrade()` and `hasFinished()`

Answer (score 0):

I made this quick and easy. Feel free to use it!

TimerID's are used to indicate which timer was the one that stopped, incase you want to have more than one timer. The GameTimerListener interface has two methods.

```
public interface GameTimerListener {

    public void SuccessfullStop(int TimerID);
    public void AbortedStop(int TimerID);
}
```

This is the GameTimer class.

```
public class GameTimer implements Runnable{
private Thread TimerThread = new Thread(this);

private List<GameTimerListener> Listeners = new ArrayList<GameTimerListener>();

public static final int Seconds = 0,Minutes = 1,Hours = 2;

private int TimerID;
private int TimerSeconds;
private int Timeout = -1;

private boolean Ticking;
private boolean Paused;

public GameTimer(int TimerID){ this.TimerID = TimerID; }
public GameTimer(int TimerID,int SecondsToRun){ this.TimerID = TimerID; Timeout = SecondsToRun; }

public void run(){
    long Timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long LastTime;

    try{
        while(Ticking){
            LastTime = System.nanoTime();
            if((System.currentTimeMillis() - Timer) >= 1000){
                Timer+= 1000;

                if(!Paused){
                   TimerSeconds++;
                }

                if((Timeout - TimerSeconds) <= 0){
                    SuccessfullStop();
                    break;
                }
            }

            Thread.sleep(10);
        }
    }catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace(); }
}
private int[] TimeLeftGetter(){
    int Seconds = (Timeout - TimerSeconds);
    int Minutes = 0;
    int Hours = 0;

    for(int x = 0; x < (Timeout - TimerSeconds); x++){
        if(Seconds > 60){
            Minutes++;
            Seconds -= 60;

            if(Minutes >= 60){
                Hours++;
                Minutes -= 60;
            }
        }
    }

    Seconds = Seconds <= 0 ? 0 : Seconds;

    return new int[]{Seconds,Minutes,Hours};
}
public synchronized void start(){ 
    if(Timeout == 0){ return; }
    if(Ticking){ ForceStop(); }

    TimerSeconds = 0;
    Ticking = true;

    TimerThread = new Thread(this);
    TimerThread.start();
}
public void ForceStop(){
    try{
        Ticking = false;
        TimerThread.join();

        for(GameTimerListener rtl : Listeners)
            rtl.AbortedStop(TimerID);
    }catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace(); }
}
public String getTimeLeftByString(){
    String time = "";
    int[] Time = TimeLeftGetter();

    time = Time[Hours] + ":" + Time[Minutes] + ":" + Time[Seconds];

    return time;
}

public boolean TimeOver(){ 
    if((Timeout - TimerSeconds) <= 0) {
        return true;
    }

    return false; 
}   
private void SuccessfullStop(){ 
    Ticking = false; 

    for(GameTimerListener rtl : Listeners)
        rtl.SuccessfullStop(TimerID);
}
public void setTimeToStop(int Seconds){
    Timeout = Seconds;

    if(Ticking){ start(); }
}
public void addGameTimerListener(GameTimerListener rtl){
    if(!Listeners.contains(rtl))
        Listeners.add(rtl);
}
public void Remove(GameTimerListener rtl){
    if(Listeners.contains(rtl))
        Listeners.remove(rtl);
}
public int getTimerID(){ return TimerID; }
public int getSecondsToRun(){ return Timeout; }
public int[] getTimeLeftByInteger(){ return TimeLeftGetter(); }
public boolean NeverStops(){ return Timeout <= -1 ? true : false; }
public boolean Ticking(){ return Ticking; }
public void setPaused(boolean Value){ Paused = Value; }
}
```

This is how you would go and implement this.
On your gravestone class, let it implement GameTimerListener.

```
   public class Gravestone extends NPC implements Serializable, GameTimeListener {
```

The two methods you will use are SuccessfullStop(int TimerID):void; and AbortedStop():void;
In the method SuccessfullStop is where you will put your code for when the time is up.
Now, lets say you want to create a new Timer that runs for five minutes. This is how you do it.

```
GameTimer MyTimer = new GameTimer(10,1500);
```

The first parameter is the ID of your timer.
I decided to give it 10 as the ID, because i like the number 10.
The second parameter is how long it will run in seconds.
1500 seconds is 5 minutes.

Before you start it or anything, be sure to add the gravestone class as a listener.

```
MyTimer.addGameTimerListener(this);
```

Now, whenever you want to start the timer, just call the method:

```
MyTimer.start();
```

This will do all the work for you.
When the timer reaches 0, it will call your SuccessfullStop() method.

Now, what if you were to use two timers? Thats where the TimerID comes in use.
When the SuccessfullStop() method gets called, note the Integer that gets passed as a parameter.

```
public void SuccessfullStop(int TimerID){
    if(TimerID == MyTimer.getTimerID()){
         //If the timer that stopped was MyTimer..
         //Code goes here for your desired timer.
    }
}
```

Hope I explained myself well. If you still have any questions, feel free to ask!

Comment: Could you give me an example how to use this with the piece of code I provided?  Would I just be doing something like:
GameTimer timer = new GameTimer(5);
I'm not quite sure, could you help?